Объявление классов в main.cpp в Qt
Прошу помочь с вопросом. При объявлении и определения классов, содержащих макрос Q_OBJECT в main.cpp возникает ошибка связанная с MOC. Возможно решить данную проблему, если да, то как.

Добавьте строчку #include "main.moc" в конце
int main() {
...
}

#include "main.moc"


Спасибо! Но работает только если сборка на CMake, при использовании qmake не работает.  Есть какие либо варианты решения проблемы с qmake.
